# How to fully include another project(s) with autotools build system?

Tags: autotools, build-system

My project depends on a third-party library(-ies) in C, which itself has a working standalone autotools based build system.

I would like to have a copy of a third-party library in a source tree and compose common autotools-based build system for my project such that I can have one configure and all usual autotools strapping to do a complete one-shot build.

This system will somehow build third-party library first (using third-party's configure.ac etc, as if it was built in isolation), then compiles and links all my sources with third-party library (I'm willing to just statically link my program to third-party library and not install third-party library anywhere in a system's locations like `/usr/local` etc).

So I assume the following directory structure for a project:

```
project/
    src/
        folder_with_my_source_code/
        third-party/
            third-party-lib-1/
                src/
                Makefile.am  // native lib-1 files, prefer to keep unmodified
                configure.ac // native lib-1 files, prefer to keep unmodified
            third-party-lib-2/
                src/
                Makefile.am  // native lib-2 files, prefer to keep unmodified
                configure.ac // native lib-2 files, prefer to keep unmodified
            Makefile.am   // do I need this at all ?

        Makefile.am //this should describe how to build my files
    Makefile.am  // project's root makefile
    configure.ac // this, probably, should somehow include instructions on how to build lib-1 and lib-2 with their supplied configure.ac's ?
```

How can I create such chain-like dependent builds?

Comment: Hey @psb, you can read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) here. Generally speaking, questions on SO should target a specific problem. For example here you could have asked `How can I use autoconf to configure and build sub-projects (that also use autoconf) recursively ? ` (if that was indeed your problem, I'm not familiar with autoconf I may have misunderstood your intention) instead of asking for people's opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.67/html_node/Subdirectories.html):

> In most situations, calling `AC_OUTPUT` is sufficient to produce makefiles in subdirectories. However, `configure` scripts that control more than one independent package can use `AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS` to run `configure` scripts for other packages in subdirectories.
>
> — Macro: **AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS** (*dir* ...)
>   Make `AC_OUTPUT` run `configure` in each subdirectory *dir* in the given blank-or-newline-separated list.